# 32-bit Fortran on 64-bit Server

Tags: gcc, ubuntu, fortran, 32bit-64bit

I have a 32-bit Fortran application that I need to run on a 64-bit ubuntu server. I have verified the application on a 32-bit ubuntu machine and it runs fine; however, I get the following error when I run in on the 64-bit server:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libgfortran.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Doing some research on this, I've tried the following with no joy:

- `sudo apt-get install libgfortran3:i386` which can't locate the package
- Manually install a 32-bit .deb package of libgfortran (failed with
  error about incorrect architecture)
- Install getlibs and have it determine what the dependencies are
- Run `ldconfig -v` which finds `libgfortran.so.3 -> libgfortran.so.3.0.0` under `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:`...
- ... and then try to change the path to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to that, which did nothing (though I have to say that my knowledge gets very sparce once we start talking about library paths...)
- Check if ia32-libs are installed, which they are
- removed and re-installed libgfortran, then ran`dpkg --configure --pending` and `dpkg --path-include=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`.

I'd like to stay away from creating a 32-bit chroot if at all possible but at this point I don't if there is anything else to do that could keep me from having to do so...

Do any of you have an idea as to something else I could do? Thank you.

Comment: Using another compiler is not an option, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this was an oversight on my part or something else; but here are the two steps that fixed it all:

1. Run `sudo apt-get install gfortran` on a 64-bit machine which will install the GNU Fortran Compiler
2. Recompile the application, on the 64-bit machine, using gfortran.

The strange part was that at this point I was still not able to just copy/paste the application file to other 64-bit machines and run it. Rather, I first had to separately install gfortran on each machine, even if I wasn't planning on compiling anything. Once gfortran was installed, the application would run, no matter where it was compiled... I presume that the libgfortran3 must have been some dependency...

Comment: Of course you need the runtime libraries on all machines. If you want to avoid that, compile statically.

Comment: Of course, if you recompile, things should work. I thought, you wanted to run a 32bit fortran program *without* recompiling it. As Vladimir pointed out, you can statically link your application (with the `-static` flag), then it will have no library dependencies and you should be able to run it on all your machines.

Comment: Right, that part makes sense. What confused me was that half of my machines (the 32-bit ones) did not need me to install gfortran and I could just run an external application (i.e. one that was not compiled on that machine) on them. On the 64-bit machines this did not work and I had to separately install gfortran to run an external application (compiling was not needed). I guess I expected that both versions of ubuntu would have the same packages installed, independent of whether it is 32 or 64 bit.

Answer (score 1):

Try to install the package `lib32gfortran3`, as that would install the 32 bit version of the libgfortran library. Before starting the program, you may eventually need to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/lib32:"` but probably it will run also without this.